# Can DIFFERENT IntentServices run in parallel?

Tags: android

Im having a little difficulty understanding one rule about IntentServices.

From [Creating a Background Service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) :

> Work requests run sequentially. If an operation is running in an IntentService, and you send **it** another request, the request waits until the first operation is finished.

I dont understand if this implies to different calls to the SAME IntentService, or even to different IntentServices.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say you start an `IntentService`, and it is performing a network request (immediately). You now request the `IntentService` to perform another task. This time, instead of immediately performing the network call, it will wait for the previous request to finish if it didn't. This applies for the SAME `IntentService`.

If you create another `IntentService` it will perform the first request immediately, but not subsequent requests.

Comment: So there're no limitations on executions of different IntentServices ? This is what i was really asking.

Comment: Well, the limitation will be if that same `IntentService` is already performing a task. If it is not already performing a task, it will execute immediately since it doesn't have to wait for the previous task to finish.

Comment: So, this actually means that each IntentService is executed on its own worker thread ? Anyway, that's really good to know. The majority of the background tasks in my app are based on IntentServices. Wanted to make sure performance is not degraded.

Comment: Yes, that is the advantage of using `IntentService` as compared to a regular `Service`. It spawns its own `Thread` to do the work.

Comment: For more info you can go through :-https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html